# CURL - This request requires HTTP authentication

Tags: php, http, curl

I have the following code:

```
$curl = curl_init($query);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

I did upload it as [AppFog](https://www.appfog.com/) application and it is working fine.
The issue is when I try to run the same code on Windows Server 2008 IIS7 or on WAMP.

I get the following message from the server:

```
HTTP Status 401 - 
type Status report
message description **This request requires HTTP authentication ().**
```

In seems that I'm not sending the credentials, but 'request_header' has the following value:

```
POST /example HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic example // deliberately removed
Host: example.com
Accept: */*
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Any ideas what might be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: does the user:pass you're trying to use actually work on that Windows server?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to third party server. So the credentials and the URL are the same in both cases.

Comment: @MarcB is right on point. The username and password need to actually authenticate with the server if I remember correctly. If you switched servers, you need to switch your user/pass as appropriate.

Comment: @Kevin I dont get the point. Example.com is server with ServiceNow instance on it and I have only one username and password combination. It should not matter if I try to access from the Windows Server machine or some other machine. The credentials stay the same.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I solved it by change the

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

to be

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
```